# Dragon Ball Z TCCG (old style before GT came out) collectors sales costs

Tags: pricing, dragon-ball-z-ccg

I have have a collections of many dragon ball z tccg cards since they started to come out. I have them in a collection as well as personally played with ones (collection ones aren't played with).

I have been saving them for years to sell. The rule of thumb is that anything that is a collections gains value over time. It's been about 15-18 years since I bought these.

However, about 8 years ago I went looking for prices and I found them to be worth pennies... now I am looking again and they are even more worthless!

This game rivaled Pokemon and Yu-Gi-Oh back then, so I am unsure of why these cards are now worth so little, can anyone explain this to me?

These cards are out of print and not sold anywhere anymore. Many of the cards in the collection I have are holographic first edition/ second edition cards. There is no way that these are worth .35c to a 1.50 **still** after almost 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll borrow an answer from [The Street](https://www.thestreet.com/story/13269749/1/7-collectibles-that-arent-completely-worthless.html).

> The collectible market is a tricky one, and a lot of what people believe will be valuable winds up becoming completely worthless (remember that '90s Beanie Baby craze?). The sector evolves over time, and interests -- and generations -- change.

The basics of supply and demand. You unfortunately selected a collectible that has little demand.

Comment: I think your link isn't working...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks! Just corrected the url paste error.  =)

Comment: Dragon Ball is very very popular still though....

Comment: @user24124 Popular does not necessarily mean highly collectible... Popularity has to outstrip demand to create value. That is why trying to guess what will become collectible is a gamble at best.

Comment: yeah well demand does not equal being more valuable. its the rarity of something and what a person is willing to pay to have it.